# Move "Add to Cart" button and variation dropdown bellow price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have one problem with my Woo Store that cant resolve myself. I want to move add to cart button and variation selector just bellow [product](https://gopacka.com/product/canny-pack/) price. I tryed almost all codes that found into stackoverflow (new and oldest ones) but dont make change nothing of that. When insert this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form', 
'second_button_single_variation', 30 );
function second_button_single_variation() {
global $product;
echo '<br>
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">'. 
esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ).'</button>';}
```

It add Just Add to Cart button, but not on place that i wanted. I followed [BBlomer manual](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/) for single product page, but dont make change any of that codes / hooks  i found there. Any help here? To show just where want to put add to cart.

EDIT: I found this code that print button where i need:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data- 
product_sku="%s" class="button %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
    esc_attr( $product->id ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
    $product->is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
    esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
),
$product );
?>
```

but print me button for Variation Options, but wihtout dropdown selector.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this action hook in a WooCommerce core

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
```

To get your requirement, You need to remove this hook and add hook again somewhat like this in your functions.php .

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price_callback', 10 );
function woocommerce_template_single_price_callback(){
    /*Play with Woocommerce Data  Here*/
    echo 'PRice';
    echo 'Button';
}
```

Comment: Found that hook into content-single-product.php template, and commented it, after that added your function into functions.php from theme, but makes no change.

Comment: I found also that function into file wc-template-hooks.php and commented.. but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

My working code:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Custom Loop Add to Cart.
 *
 * Template with quantity and ajax.
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
global $product;
?>

<?php if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

    <a href="<?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" class="button"><?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></a>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php
        $link = array(
            'url'   => '',
            'label' => '',
            'class' => ''
        );
        switch ( $product->product_type ) {
        case "variable" :
        $link = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
        $label = woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart();
        break;
            case "grouped" :
                $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_text', __( 'View options', 'woocommerce' ) );
            break;
            case "external" :
                $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) );
            break;
            default :
                if ( $product->is_purchasable() ) {
                    $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_url', esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) );
                    $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ) );
                    $link['class']  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_class', 'add_to_cart_button' );
                } else {
                    $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'not_purchasable_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                    $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'not_purchasable_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }
            break;
        }

    ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<!--end code -->
```

Many Thanks for all that tryed to help. :)